# Apache Reverse Proxy with IPv6 troubles

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, httpd, ipv6

Problem: IPv6 Client attempting to contact Server behind reverse proxy fails.

In this example, client and server reside on the same machine.

Client's IPv6 configuration:

```
ip --oneline addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN \    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000\    link/ether 00:1e:67:57:31:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
2: eth0    inet6 2001:db8:0:1::131/64 scope global \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0    inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe57:313d/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Since in this case the client knows its server resides on the same machine, it attempts to connect to port 443 on its own IP 2001:db8:0:1::131 .

An Apache server is running as a reverse proxy, listening on 443 and forwarding to the server on 42502.

My .conf file:

```
ProxyPass /api/xml http://localhost4:42502 retry=0
```

Listening processes:

```
netstat -lnutp | grep "42502\|443"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42502               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      68163/python
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      68513/httpd
```

So Apache is listening correctly on all IPv6 port 443, and the python (Twisted) process is listening on all IPv4 port 42502.

localhost4 is appropriately defined:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

and pingable

```
ping localhost4
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
```

But the connection fails. Here's what Apache says:

```
2001:db8:0:1::131 - -... "POST /api/xml HTTP/1.0" 502 396
```

and

```
[error] [client 2001:db8:0:1::131] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: localhost4 returned by /api/xml
```

Looks like the failure is Apache trying to reach the Python process on 42502. If I change localhost4 to explicitly point to 127.0.0.1, that equally fails.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Exact Apache version:

```
rpm -qa | grep httpd
httpd-tools-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
httpd-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
```

UPDATE:
Server on localhost4 is responsive

```
curl -g -k -X POST http://localhost4:42502
Unauthenticated user
```

UPDATE:
Performing tcpdump on port 42503, I see that nothing is attempting to be sent to the backend server. Performing strace on Apache, I see:

```
strace -p 89954 -f -ff -s 10
accept4(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(39850), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:0:1::131", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 13
semop(9928708, {{0, 1, SEM_UNDO}}, 1)   = 0
getsockname(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(443), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:0:1::131", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
fcntl(13, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
brk(0x7f27e6dbb000)                     = 0x7f27e6dbb000
read(13, "\26\3\1\0\364\1\0\0\360\3"..., 8000) = 249
writev(13, [{"\26\3\3\0:\2\0\0006\3"..., 2484}], 1) = 2484
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 65535000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
read(13, "\26\3\3\0\206\20\0\0\202\0"..., 8000) = 190
writev(13, [{"\26\3\3\0\312\4\0\0\306\0"..., 258}], 1) = 258
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 65535000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
read(13, "\27\3\3\0\341-\323\5\227\256"..., 8000) = 230
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 0)         = 14
bind(14, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(14, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=89954, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendto(14, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3N\25"..., 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
recvmsg(14, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"0\0\0\0\24\0\2\0N\25"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 48
recvmsg(14, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"@\0\0\0\24\0\2\0N\25"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 192
recvmsg(14, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\24\0\0\0\3\0\2\0N\25"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20
close(14)                               = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 14
fstat(14, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=158, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f27e660f000
read(14, "127.0.0.1 "..., 4096)         = 158
read(14, "", 4096)                      = 0
close(14)                               = 0
munmap(0x7f27e660f000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 14
connect(14, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:0:1::128", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)   = 1 ([{fd=14, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(14, "0\315\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0"..., 52, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 52
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=14, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(14, FIONREAD, [133])              = 0
recvfrom(14, "0\315\205\203\0\1\0\0\0\1"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(53), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:0:1::128", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 133
close(14)                               = 0
write(7, "[Wed Feb 0"..., 125)          = 125
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 65535000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN}])
read(13, "\27\3\3\2\217-\323\5\227\256"..., 8000) = 660
writev(13, [{"\27\3\3\0\305)z\0A7"..., 627}], 1) = 627
write(10, "2001:db8:0"..., 84)          = 84
writev(13, [{"\25\3\3\0\32)z\0A7"..., 31}], 1) = 31
shutdown(13, 1 /* send */)              = 0
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}])
read(13, 0x7fff9e1d5740, 512)           = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
close(13)                               = 0
read(5, 0x7fff9e1d596f, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

The line:

```
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 14
```

shows the name localhost4 is being looked up and found in:

```
read(14, "127.0.0.1 "..., 4096)         = 158
```

The line:

```
write(7, "[Wed Feb 0"..., 125)          = 125
```

is the error being output to the error log.

Conclusions until now: once the request from the client to Apache occurs, Apache does not succeed in connecting to localhost4. I don't see any proof of Apache even attempting to open a connection. Apache can't seem to find it even though netstat shows that python is successfully opened and listening at that address and port.

Comment: What was the error message when you tried `http://127.0.0.1:42502`? Did it actually say `DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1`? Did you restart apache after your latest change to /etc/hosts?

Comment: Same error message. `proxy: DNS lookup failure for: 127.0.0.1 returned by /api/xml` . I perform `apache -k restart` for each change.

Comment: Does it work with `http://localhost6:42502`?

Comment: Yes, it works with localhost6:42502. That is to say, direct communication client->server works as expected. But for some reason Apache as a reverse proxy is failing.

Comment: Let me ask a bit more clearly then. Does `ProxyPass /api/xml http://localhost6:42502 retry=0` work, and if not, what error is logged?

Comment: `[error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to [::1]:42502 (localhost6) failed` This is the correct response. Because the server is listening on IPv4, if Apache tries to reach it on an IPv6 address, it should fail.

Comment: That tells us that `ProxyPass` only tries to resolve the hostname to an IPv6 address and not to an IPv4 address. That explains why neither `127.0.0.1` nor `localhost4` works, because resolving those to IPv6 addresses doesn't work. I don't know why `ProxyPass` apparently doesn't support IPv4 in your setup.